# Need to purchase a Serial port that can be soldered to a motherboard

Tags: serial

All I can find are adapters and gender changers. Where can I find one with actual leads I can solder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for a connector, how about something like 
[this one](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_1952839_-1) ?

Comment: Yes!! That is what I need. What did you look up to find that? All my searches came up with cables and such.

Comment: @sadse: when looking for a part like that, I usually make the rounds at several vendor sites. Digikey usually has more options than Jameco, but that can make it more difficult to settle on a specific item, but OTOH options are sometimes indispensable.

Comment: Adding terms like 'through hole' (or 'smd') might help with the search results.